# Finding the limit of a function of multiple constants

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

How can I find the limit of this expression as L_cake approaches infinity? I know that all other symbols are constant.

[image]

I tried:

```
sim_sol2=smp.limit(sol2,L_cake,oo)
```

But the output is just the original equation.

Comment: The limit is going to be 1/4, right?  The first term goes to zero, the second term goes to 1/4.  All the other constants are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a computer here, pen an paper will suffice.

1. For the first term you have `a / (b + c * x)` so as `x` tends to infinity it dominates those constants and the function tends to `1/x`, which in the limit becomes zero.
2. The second part we can rewrite as  `ax /(4ax + 4bc)` which is really just `ax /(4ax + d)` because 4bc is just "another constant". And again because `x` dominates constants as it tends to infinity, the function itself will tend to `ax / 4ax`, in which `ax` cancels out and we're left with `1/4`.

And if we want the limit for L_filter instead of L_cake (with L_cake fixed) then the limit is `1/2`. No need for computers there either, the formula's not complex enough to warrant it, if you're solving for a single variable =)

Answer (score 2):

SymPy is being cautious because it doesn't know if the other symbols are finite or not. Just make everything finite and then ask for the limit (or use the big-term-little-term thinking given by others):

```py
from sympy import *
Kc, Lf, Lc, Kf = var('Kc, Lf, Lc, Kf',finite=True)
eq=Kc*Lf/(2*Kc*Lf + 2*Kf*Lc) + Kf*Lc/(4*Kc*Lf + 4*Kf*Lc)
>>> limit(eq,Lc,oo)
1/4
```